# How can I categorize a datetime series in a data frame with the Broadcast weeks calendar?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datetime column in a dataframe and would like to populate another column with the corresponding week number according to the Broadcast calendar. The Broadcast calendar separates days by weeks a little differently than the regular calendar and I have it in another dataframe which contains the following columns: from_date, to_date, range (type pd.date_range), week_number.

I have tried the numpy.where function with the `isin()` function but I get type errors. I also tried iterating through and applying a lambda to check if the date falls between each range in the broadcast calendar to no avail.

```
df['WEEK'] = np.where(df['DATE_TIME'].isin(broadcast_calendar['date_range']))
```

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: class 'pandas.core.indexes.datetimes.DatetimeIndex' is not convertible to datetime

Example data frames:

```
broadcast_calendar = pd.DataFrame({
    'range': ['01/07-01/13', '01/14-01/20', '01/21-01/27', '01/28-02/03'],
    'week': [2, 3, 4, 5]
})

df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['foo', 'bar'], 'date': ['01/16', '02/01']})
```

I would like the item 'foo' to have a column showing that it belongs to week 3 of the broadcast calendar, and bar should belong to week 5.

I also tried this:

```
df['week'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: np.where(x > broadcast_calendar.from_date and x < pd.to_date))
```

But I get this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO!  This question will be much easier for people to answer if you can add an [mcve].